# Copy-list-initialization assignment has different results for structs with same type members but different definition order

Tags: c++, enums, initialization, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

enum struct option_t : uint8_t
{
    INVALID         = 0,
    RESERVED        = 1,
    TEST_OPTION     = 2
};

struct Trace_1
{
    option_t   option  {option_t::INVALID};
    uint32_t   iter    {0};
};

struct Trace_2
{
    uint32_t   iter    {0};
    option_t   option  {option_t::INVALID};
};


int main()
{
    Trace_1 trace1{};
    Trace_2 trace2{};
    trace2 = {0};
    trace1 = {0};
}
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADMAKykAA6oCoRODB7evnppGY4CIWGRLDFxABy2mPZFDEIETMQEOT5%2BAXaYDlmNzQQlEdGxCckKTS1teVy2EwOhQ%2BUjlQCUtqhexMjsHCYaAIJeGUYA1F6hBJUA%2BgQnJvEAImcMGcBh6CfICM33VgdHoWAZwuXAAbDc7o9nq93icFAgSARfntDscgedBPEzBD7k8vC88G9MB8LsiDiiKQdGD44QRiF4HCdUCl6hCQMDBNckeSAOx/fYnQUnACS4QAavsgsKnkLZZCnhpSCjZQAlbBCbAqsXYGVy%2BUnGbKoUAFXVxquAHllMbhRbwvqzBSeQ8yfsUeN6YzjcQmNsrlwnfzZczWbdBSGsoKTHyIwIbiAQKKJVKXc7XbKMQQsRDBYRYnLoxYNNGXfF%2BSXXR6Gbdvb7MFdHbyg0LM9mwyc88QC3zi2my0bwyysjmmUOBFGY2OGPHE%2BLJdKK/3eaXy%2BSDhcTiwmKEICtAwOTrW/VwTnS6wG%2BYvm4Kj/WzKefdtHZe%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%2BSIEU2TiHCVgdjJimqZpwwgXpxmivwIgTr0fgRtEcQJs9qaVHUaK5tIYyfRSDrFZQlWeOJi0yqN25UCoUnycp6nVIdumGaZiAPGk82Oa4LmtZEvnSFoyQuHonkzB5LhEkkMxKnU9TQVlhvFeV1WDr42xNZ5qjFbMQm1d7gey6OjJnEkIA)

For above code, the list initialization makes an assignment to one temporary object.
`Trace_1` and `Trace_2` have the same member types but differ in the declaration order; consequently the assignment result is different.
`trace2 = {0}` can compile but `trace1 = {0}` can't, with the error:

```
<source>:32:12: error: no viable overloaded '='
    trace1 = {0};
    ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~
<source>:15:8: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const Trace_1'
struct Trace_1
       ^
<source>:15:8: note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'Trace_1'
struct Trace_1
```

I think the initializer `0` in the initialization list can be converted to the member types in both `Trace_1` and `Trace_2` without narrowing conversion, so the list initialization assignment should work. Any thoughts here?

Comment: The problem is the enumeration initialization. `enum struct` defines it to be a [*scoped* enumeration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations), with a strong and distinct type which isn't really compatible  with the underlying type. You can't initialize `option_t` with the integer value `0`. You *must* use `option_t::INVALID`.

Comment: As of C++17, you can list initialize a scoped enumeration using an integral value without the static_cast

Comment: and, the **trace2 = {0}** expression can pass build

Answer (score 5):

In [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), all of the initializers (in your case just `0`) are used to initialize the data members in declaration order.

- for `Trace_2`, the `0` initializes `iter`, which is of type `uint32_t` (OK)
- for `Trace_1`, the `0` initializes `option_t` which is an `enum class` (ERROR)

You might assume that using `0` must be valid for `Trace_1`, because `option_t{0}` is valid (since C++17). However, the initialization of members [takes place using *copy initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Initializing_Elements), as if by:

```cpp
option_t option = 0;
```

There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `option_t`, so this is not allowed. It's not about whether `0 -> option_t` is a narrowing conversion, it's about the syntax `= 0` never being allowed for scoped enumerations (`enum class`).

On a side note, GCC gives us a much better error when attempting to use `{0}` to initialize (not assign) `trace1`:

```
error: cannot convert 'int' to 'option_t' in initialization
   24 |     Trace_1 trace1{0};
      |                    ^
      |                    |
      |                    int
```

#### Possible Solutions

```cpp
// works because we now use direct list init, not copy init
trace1 = {option_t{0}};

// works because we now use the default member initializers in Trace_1
trace1 = {};

// same as above; more explicit, slightly redundant style
trace1 = Trace_1{};
```

#### Notes

*Note 1: You don't need `= {0}` to value-initialize a `struct` in C++, only in C. Don't do it unless you want to be explicit about initializing the first member to zero.*

*Note 2: `enum struct` is allowed, but you might want to prefer `enum class`, since this is a much more popular style and will surprise fewer people.*